# How can I increase my app's device compatibility?

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility

I've found that I can't find my app on google play with any of our new Android phones(a Galaxy Note, and a HTC Evo 4g lte). I figure it has to do with my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example"
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.15" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" android:resizeable="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges=    "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I figure it has to do with my manifest.

That would be correct.

I would start by deleting your `<compatible-screens>` element, or at least expanding the list of size/density combinations. As it stands, out of 16 possibilities, you claim to only support 4 of them, and some (e.g., `small`/`ldpi`) are fairly unpopular. If you are trying to say that you support all sizes and densities, delete the `<compatible-screens>` element.

Answer (score 7):

```
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi"/>
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi"/>
</compatible-screens>
```

this limits your compatibility to devices with small screen and ldpi. So a small screen with mdpi will not be supported. I would remove this block, the `<supports-screens>` should be enough to make it visible to all devices out there.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with your manifest file. For example, you can find an app through the "Search" option on a smartphone even if the app is for tablets only.

The reason why you cannot find your app is that is not popular enough to show up in your results, it will appear after many pages of apps.

To see your app, just type the package of the application  instead of the name.
Eg: com.example.myapp

Comment: He didn't say how he searched for the app and the manifest has some heavy impact on the fact, if an app can be found.